# Using $http interceptor with custom fields in a typesafe manner in angular + typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I currently implemented an angular `$http` interceptor adding custom headers to requests based on a localstorage value (I need to implement a "Su" feature in my app)

I need to "deactivate" this behaviour on some special requests (=I need to be able to configure this on a per-request basis), and I'd like to do this by putting an extra config parameter denoting this when calling my `$http` methods.

The interceptor is looking like this :

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push((localStorageService: ng.local.storage.ILocalStorageService) => {
    return {
        request: (config: ng.IRequestShortcutConfig) => {
            var su = localStorageService.get<string>('Su');
            if(su && !("avoidSudo" in config)){
                config.headers.Su = `{ "principal": "${su}" }`;
            }
            return config;
        }
    }
});
```

And the `$http` service call is looking like this when I want to deactivate my "su" feature :

```
this.$http.get('/api/sessions/current', { avoidSudo: true })
```

In typescript 1.6, this code doesn't compile as `$http.get()`'s second argument is expected to be a `ng.IRequestShortcutConfig` which obviously doesn't contain my specific `avoidSudo` field (Typescript compilation error is perfectly right here)

I can workaround the compilation error by replacing the `{ avoidSudo: true }` by `<any>{ avoidSudo: true }` but this is clearly not ideal in terms of typesafety

I tried to create a new `SkipSudoRequestShortcutConfig` dedicated class (implementing `ng.IRequestShortcutConfig`) for this purpose. Something like this :

```
module mymodule {
  export class SkipSudoRequestShortcutConfig implements ng.IRequestShortcutConfig { 
    // For testing purposes only
    _noSudo: boolean;
    constructor(
            public params?: any,
            public headers?: any,
            public xsrfHeaderName?: string,
            public xsrfCookieName?: string,
            public cache?: any,
            public withCredentials?: boolean,
            public data?: any,
            public transformRequest?: any,
            public transformResponse?: any,
            public timeout?: any,
            public responseType?: string
    ){
        this._noSudo = true;
    }
  }
}
```

called like this :

```
var config = new SkipSudoRequestShortcutConfig();
console.log(config instanceof SkipSudoRequestShortcutConfig); // Shows true
console.log(config._noSudo); // Shows true
this.$http.get('/api/sessions/current', config)
```

and used like this in the interceptor :

```
        request: (config: ng.IRequestShortcutConfig) => {
            var su = localStorageService.get<string>('Su');
            console.log(config instanceof SkipSudoRequestShortcutConfig); // Shows *false* :(
            // console.log(config._noSudo); // Doesn't compile, but if executed at runtime with a breakpoint, it works and display true
            if(su && !(config instanceof mymodule.SkipSudoRequestShortcutConfig)){
                config.headers.Su = `{ "principal": "${su}" }`;
            }
            return config;
        }
```

but once in the `request` handler, the `instanceof` test was falsy.

I was wondering what would be the best/simplest way to achieve this goal.
Do you think the `ng.IRequestShortcutConfig` is missing a special `config` field allowing to put custom fields from `$http` invocations to interceptor handlers ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Hi Fred. You probably know more about TypScript than I do, but I'd do the same: define a SkipSudoRequestShortcutConfig interface/class extending IRequestShortcutConfig. Could you provide more information (code + errors) about "the class information is not transferred by angular from the $http.get() call to the interceptor handler".

Comment: Sure ! I just updated the description reflecting my test on `SkipSudoRequestShortcutConfig `

Comment: I would make SkipSudoRequestShortcutConfig an interface that extends SkipSudoRequestShortcutConfig, and contains an optional boolean field `skipSudo`. Passing an instance of that interface to $http should work fine, since it extends SkipSudoRequestShortcutConfig. And I would make the request function of your interceptor take a SkipSudoRequestShortcutConfig instance as argument. Instead of an instanceof check, I would simply test if `config.skipSudo` is truthy. Not tested at all: I've never used TypScript with Angular 1, and don't have significant experience with TS.

Comment: I cannot take a `SkipSudoRequestShortcutConfig` instance as argument of the `request` callback because in most of cases, I will keep passing a standard `ng.IRequestShortcutConfig` to the `$http` calls.

Comment: Instead of using an interceptor, can you just override/inherit from the normal `$httpProvider` and pass normal requests through but add your `SkipSudoRequestShortcutConfig` checks to it?

Comment: @jmb.mage Something like wrapping `$http` calls into a `my$http` component which will intercept `get`/`post` etc.. methods ? I thought about it, but it will require to inject the new component potentially everywhere I use the standard `$http` service (or at least, at the locations I need to skip sudo). Moreover, I'm not sure someone (including me) will not forget to call the new `my$http` instead of the standard `$http` (interceptors were cool for that points)

Comment: @Frédéric yes.  I think that makes it easier than using an interceptor because you can control when your code is executed, before, during and after requests.  I've implemented something similar, take a look at [overriding jquery ajax](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=overriding+jquery+ajax) but of course with `$httpProvider` instead of `$.ajax`.

Comment: @Frédéric TypeScript is a bit more type-safe, but it still uses duck-typing. So, even if you pass an IRequestShortcutConfig instance, to $http, the interceptor won't really care: the only difference between an IRequestShortcutConfig and a SkipSudoRequestShortcutConfig is an optional boolean field, so that should work fine. Shouldn't it? After all, many $http calls are done by angular itself, which doesn't care about your types.

Answer (score 2):

It's important to remember that types in TypeScript are just "type helpers" and removed when transpiled to javascript. So you don't need to implement a new $http service. Instead you can just create a new type that suites your needs.

In reality it's because the angular type definition is lacking.

You can fix this by creating the following interfaces.

```
export interface IRequestShortcutConfigWithCustomConfig extends ng.IRequestShortcutConfig {
    [key: string]: any;
}
```

I'm using a dictionary style type cause that'll support everything. But you could change that to `avoidSudo: boolean;` if you don't want a general definition.

```
export interface IHttpServiceWithCustomConfig extends ng.IHttpService {
    get<T>(url: string, config?: IRequestShortcutConfigWithCustomConfig): ng.IHttpPromise<T>;
}
```

Then in your controller you just use the new interface.

```
constructor(private $http: IHttpServiceWithCustomConfig) {
    $http.get("/api/sessions/current", { avoidSudo: true }
}
```

You do the exact same with `IHttpInterceptor`

```
export interface IRequestConfigWithCustomConfig extends ng.IRequestConfig, IRequestShortcutConfigWithCustomConfig {

}

export interface IHttpInterceptorWithCustomConfig extends ng.IHttpInterceptor {
    request?: (config: IRequestConfigWithCustomConfig) => IRequestConfigWithCustomConfig | ng.IPromise<IRequestConfigWithCustomConfig>;
}
```